# How to enable route for uploads directory in phoenix framework

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have implemented file upload in phoenix framework by using these two elixir libraries arc (https://github.com/stavro/arc) and acr_ecto (https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto),

when i upload a image, it is stored in the following directory

"app_root/uploads/users/avatars/filename.jpg"

Now how do i enable route to access `app_root/uploads/users/avatars/filename.jpg` file from browser

Answer (score 2):

It can be enabled by adding [Plug.Static](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html) to app_root/lib/appname/endpoint.ex

```
plug Plug.Static,
        at: "/uploads", from: "uploads", gzip: false
```

after that you have to restart server and then you can simply call

```
MyApp.Avatar.url({user.avatar,user})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but [here](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html) it says that you can pass a tuple to the `from` key so I guess it would be something like `{:my_app, Path.join(***PATH_TO_YOUR_APP***, "uploads")}` and then you could create a little helper to generate relative paths to your files like this

```
def relative_path(filename) do
  "/users/avatars/ <> filename
end
```

I am not sure it will work but it's probably done somehow closely :)